# To update multiple documents in mongoose (Node JS)

Tags: express, mongoose, mongodb-query, nodes

I'd like to update multiple documents with query that is made by object array. However I found that only one documents had been changed.

```
var split = num.toString().split(',');
var list = new Array;
for ( var i in split ) {
    var pk = {
        "_id" : split[i],
        "id" : user.id
    }
    list.push(pk);
}

var vm = {name:"robert",category:"media"};

database.bookModel.findOneAndUpdate(list, vm, { multi: true }, function (err, result) {
....
```

Following Approach I couldn't follow to update Multiple document.
I'm using findOneAndUpdate query that I found only one record will be changed.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to use criteria with object array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bulk find and update,

```
var bulk = db.Model.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var vm = {
  name: "robert",
  category: "media"
};

for (var i in split) {
  var pk = {
    "_id": split[i],
    "id": user.id
  }
  bulk.find(pk).update({
    $set: vm
  });
}

bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to resolve my issue Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'findOneAndUpdate' it will only update one document, try 'update', you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for advising me. I'll use "update" behalf of "findOneAndUpdate" next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query like this:

```
database.bookModel.update(list, vm, {
    multi: true
}).then(() => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Data updated successfully!'
    })
}).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json({
        error: err
    });
});
```